# Cyrus-sasl config in Postfix in FreeBSD without dovecot

Tags: postfix, freebsd, saslauthd

Good Afternoon, I have installed a Freebsd 12.1 with postfix and when trying to start see this in /var/log/maillog

```
    warning: SASL: Connect to /usr/local/lib/sasl2/smtpd.conf failed: No such file or directory
Jul 16 16:01:57 mailrelay4 postfix/smtpd[10012]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms
Jul 16 16:01:58 mailrelay4 postfix/master[8806]: warning: process /usr/local/libexec/postfix/smtpd pid 10012 exit status 1
Jul 16 16:01:58 mailrelay4 postfix/master[8806]: warning: /usr/local/libexec/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
```

in /usr/local/lib/sasl2 I created the file smtpd.conf and inside typed this:

```
pwcheck_method: saslauthd
mech_list: PLAIN LOGIN
```

the permissions on that file are:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 postfix  wheel    48B Jul 16 16:01 /usr/local/lib/sasl2/smtpd.conf
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Check your configuration. It looks like somewhere you have put the path to a configuration file, where it was expecting a local socket or network host and port.

Comment: If I remove the line it gives this warning: SASL: Connect to smtpd failed: No such file or directory
Jul 16 16:34:08 mailrelay4 postfix/smtpd[24141]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms

Comment: What line are you talking about? Your post doesn't show any configuration.

Comment: this lines:      #smtpd_sasl_path = /usr/local/lib/sasl2/smtpd.conf                                                                                    
#smtpd_sasl_local_domain =                                                                                                            
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous

Comment: That's definitely not supposed to be a path. See http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html#server_cyrus

Comment: whet i type : smtpd_sasl_auth_type = smtpd, it reponds this :                                                                                                             warning: SASL: Connect to smtpd failed: No such file or directory
Jul 16 16:59:43 mailrelay4 postfix/smtpd[31795]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms